# How to design recognition mechanism of a provisioning system?

Tags: architecture, software-design

I am building a provisioning system, where other software/app/device/user would connect to it. I want a create a recognition mechanism so that I can identify the thing that is connecting to the system is a valid identity.

Some kind of key, specific to the connecting software. The requirement is that the key should be easily understandable to the provisioning system but difficult to crack for the others.

I can simply create some random characters (key) and provide it to the connecting devices during the registration process, by which they will connect to the provisioning system later on, then there would arise some problems. One is the identity theft, anyone can steal it and can connect to the provisioning system; another one is that someone mischifely can distribute the key. For both the cases the system would fail to verify the legitimacy of the connecting app.

Any suggestion to solve this scenario greatly appreciable.

*I have asked the same question in [programmers.stackexchange.com](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/324405/how-to-design-recognition-mechanism-of-a-provisioning-system) 10 days ago hoping that designated forum would be best for this topic, unfortunately I haven't received anything. I have flagged the question asking moderator to move it to SO, but my request was rejected.*

I hope I can have some help here.

### Technology stack

My primary preference of implementation language is Java. The protocol of connection is SSL/TLS over HTTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Identity distribution

> One is the identity theft, anyone can steal it and can connect to the
> provisioning system; another one is that someone mischifely can
> distribute the key. For both the cases the system would fail to verify
> the legitimacy of the connecting app.

In most authentication schema the client is responsible for protecting it's own identity. When the client knows the authentication protocol and is willingly sharing all details that allows other clients to impersonate him/it then it becomes virtually impossible to protect and guarantee the identity of that client.

If you are afraid that your clients will share their identity then you would have to make it very hard for third-party clients themselves to figure out how they actually get authenticated. One way I could think of is that every client would be forced to install a proprietary software on their machine through which the authentication would be made. The software would have to be very hard to reverse engineer in order to remain secure, but even that is not infallible.

I think the first thing to do would be to identify why you are so concerned about guaranteeing the identity of your clients and why it would be appealing to them to share their identity?

For instance, most if not all MMORG games will prevents players to share their account. They certainly do so to get more sales, but another motivation may be to prevent an account from being played much more often than true single-player accounts and thus progress much faster. Since identity sharing becomes an advantage they cannot only rely on the players to keep their identity safe and they must come up with strategies such as IP address checking, geo-localizing through the ISP, unusual playtimes, etc. but all these additional measures can be overcome. Perhaps game designers should work on finding authentication strategies where the players aren't involved in the authentication process.

Finally, in any case, often changing the authentication protocol or details will certainly make it harder to both, steal or willingly share identity, but it's not without a cost.

## Authentication motivation?

Another reason you may want to ensure the identity of the client is that you must be able to trust the information that they send. In this case the goal is completely different and rather than looking at how we may validate the identity of the client perhaps we should be looking at strategies to validate their input. Input validation strategies will be specific to your domain and will sometime require architecture changes.

An example I can think of is how the [Blockchain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blockchain_(database)) works to guarantee transactional integrity among various clients.

## What is the risk?

Finally, before even considering a specific solution to your problem you should define what is the actual risk that an illegitimate client uses your provisioning system. Only then you will be able to choose an enlightened solution. A good solution will strike balance between risk and complexity.

Answer (score 0):

So, you want an authentication mechanism without storing API keys on your side? Take a look on [JSON Web Tokens](https://float-middle.com/json-web-tokens-jwt-vs-sessions/), maybe it is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to be quite technology-abstract, so it is difficult to find a 'correct' answer. You should consider asking your question with a bit more technical detail (on which technology (language, server, ...) is your server based. How do others connect (which protocol, transport layer, etc.).

But to give an answer on your level, you should have a look at asymmetric keys (public/private key pairs). If you fear distribution of keys, you could combine this approach with either a hardware solution (dongle, card) or you could calculate a hardware identifier (based on MAC address, hardware serial id, ...) on first-time login and tie the authentication key to that (but this will lead to support effort, because systems can change, users can buy new hardware, ...)

Comment: First of all I would like to express my gratitude for the suggestion you have provided. I have updated my question with the technology stack.

Comment: So, are you providing an API for others to embrace and want to hand out API keys as sampleNull suggests in their answer?

Comment: No, I am not providing any API. The connectable things can connect by any means to the provisioning system, but the way of connection must be over HTTP.

Comment: Would it be feasible to issue HTTPS Client Certificates to the connectable things? Then the clients could authenticate themselves this way and you could e.g. configure the server so that no two clients with the same certificate could connect.

Comment: Yes. Of course. In fact the Certificate will be issued for each client. Though there is a chance that someone steal that certificate. Now as you mentioned of configuring server so that no two clients with same certificate could connect. Did you mean connect at a same time?

Comment: Well you could think of different approaches. Prevent logins at the same time or in a certain timespan, geolocate the source IP and prevent logins that come from different locations during a certain timespan etc.